# Cannot declare 'TimeAgoPipe' in an NgModule. (timeAgo pipe not working in angular 9)

Tags: angular, pipe, angular9, timeago

After moving to angular 9, I can't compile it because of timeAgo pipe. I just get this error : `Cannot declare 'TimeAgoPipe' in an NgModule as it's not a part of the current compilation`. then I searched for the reason and got some info from [here](https://github.com/AndrewPoyntz/time-ago-pipe/issues/33).I have solved this by disabling the iot.  but I couldn't find any more solution. this is my `app.moudle.ts`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { AuthService } from './_services/auth.service';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { AlertifyService } from './_services/alertify.service';
import {DatepickerModule, BsDatepickerModule} from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MemberListComponent } from './members/member-list/member-list.component';
import { ListsComponent } from './lists/lists.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { appRoutes } from './routes';
import { MemberCardComponent } from './members/member-card/member-card.component';
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { MemberDetailsComponent } from './members/member-details/member-details.component';
import {TabsModule} from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';
import { MemberDetailResolver } from './_resolvers/member-detail.resolver';
import { MemberListResolver } from './_resolvers/member-list.resolver';
import {NgxGalleryModule} from 'ngx-gallery-9';
import { MemberEditComponent } from './members/member-edit/member-edit.component';
import { MemberEditResolver } from './_resolvers/member-edit.resolver';
import { PreventUnsavedChanges } from './_guards/prevent-unsaved.guard';
import { PhotoUploderComponent } from './members/photo-uploder/photo-uploder.component';
import { FileUploadModule } from 'ng2-file-upload';
import {TimeAgoPipe} from 'time-ago-pipe';


export function tokenGetter(){
  return localStorage.getItem('token');
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    MemberListComponent,
    ListsComponent,
    MessagesComponent,
    MemberCardComponent,
    MemberDetailsComponent,
    MemberEditComponent,
    PhotoUploderComponent,
    TimeAgoPipe
      ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgxGalleryModule,
    FileUploadModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter,
        whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:5000'],
        blacklistedRoutes: ['localhost:5000/auth']
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    AlertifyService,
    MemberDetailResolver,
    MemberListResolver,
    MemberEditResolver,
    PreventUnsavedChanges
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I was wondering if there is way to use this or even any alternative which is support by angular 9.